# Class 'User_model_new' not found!!! what might be the reason?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2

```
<?php
 // my user_model_new.php file in application/model folder
 class User_model_new extends CI_Model{
    private $random_property;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    protected get_random_property()
    {
        return $this->random_property;
    }
 }
 // my article_model.php file in application/model folder
 class Article_model extends User_model_new{
     function show_random()
     {
         $this->get_random_property();
     }  

 }
```

but now if i run the code codeIgniter show this error "class User_model_new" not found. What is wrong here? Help me i'm stuck because of it.

Comment: How do you load user_model? Could you show your autoload file?

Comment: what if i load them in controller construct?

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
 class Article_model extends User_model{
```

**With**

```
 class Article_model extends User_model_new{
```

Comment: lol apologies it's User_model_new itself, i made a mistake in question :(

Comment: @avinashizhere so please edit it and do not forget to add `User_model_new` class file into Article_model because you are not making `User_model_new` class available for `Article_model`

Comment: @avinashizhere what you can also do is add `$this->load->model('User_model_new');` this line in `Article_model` construct method..

Comment: @avinashizhere or add `require base_url().'application/models/user_model_new.php';` this line in Article model.